# call sql from a user defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server, execute

Is it possible with SQL Server 2008 to execute sql from a variabele in a user defined function? Or is using a stored procedure the only solution?

I have an sql statement saved in a variabele

```
@mySqlStatement = "select * from someTable"
```

I want to execute the above statement from within a user defined function, is that possible?

Comment: can plss you tell what you except ?

Comment: Are you asking about making dynamic SQL based on the input param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, with restrictions. Please read [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/29/sql-server-user-defined-functions-udf-limitations/).

Also, be very careful about queries you write that are to be executed in a UDF. Query optimization can be a real problem and so can the number of times queries get executed, depending on how the UDF is called.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean is it possible to run SQL from an external programming language? Of course it is.

Answer (score 0):

For sure yes! You can execute SQL code without using a stored procedure..
(if this is the question..)