# What this dynamic query missing and doesn't return a result?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I have following scalar function but the problem is that it doesn't return actual result but returns a query.

Could somebody guide me on it what I am missing here or making wrong?

I have formed the following function

```
ALTER function test(@QueId int, @Answer varchar(250)) RETURNS VARCHAR(500) AS   
BEGIN  
   DECLARE @STR varchar(4000) 
   DECLARE @QRY AS VARCHAR(1000)

   SELECT @QRY=
     'SELECT @str = COALESCE(@str + '';'','''') + AnswerText '+  
     'FROM SurveyQuestionAnswerTypes WHERE AnswerType=(Select AnswerType From SurveyQuestions Where QuestionID=' + 
     CAST(@QueId AS VARCHAR(4)) + ')AND AnswerValue in (' + replace(@Answer,'^',',') +')'

   --EXEC sp_executesql @QRY, '@STR VARCHAR(4000)', @STR
   RETURN @QRY 
END
```

Instead of returning a result it returns

```
SELECT @str = COALESCE(@str + ';','') + AnswerText 
FROM SurveyQuestionAnswerTypes 
WHERE AnswerType = (Select AnswerType 
                    From SurveyQuestions 
                    Where QuestionID=25)AND AnswerValue in (3,4,5,6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well - it returns the query because you told it to do so!

Look at your code: you have commented out the line that would actually **execute** the dynamic SQL (`EXEC sp_executsql .....`), and instead you're returning the query (`@QRY`) as a string:

```
--EXEC sp_executesql @QRY, '@STR VARCHAR(4000)', @STR
RETURN @QRY
```

Just change that to execute the query instead of returning its string representation....

Comment: true you are, but when i so it like this it throws the error, Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: probably a **function** is the wrong way to go - try to convert this to a stored procedure. Functions do have quite a few limitations in what they can do (or cannot do)

Comment: YES YOU ARE CORRECT, I LEARNT IT AFTERA LOT STUSY ON NET, BUT WHAT SHOULD I DO THEN, I NEED TO CALL THIS FUCNTION FROM MY VIEW, BUT THE PROB IS THAT HOW TO CALL THIS SP FROM THE VIEW TOO, WHAT SHOULD I DO THEN..

Comment: MOST OF ALL - you shouldn't be SHOUTING AT ALL by typing in ALL UPPERCASE :......

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax, this might work for you:

```
Exec (@QRY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute "exec" or "sp_executesql" nor can execute a stored procedure in a function.

you can refer this 
[blog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/29/sql-server-user-defined-functions-udf-limitations/)

OR this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585502/call-sql-from-a-user-defined-function)